# Session User management android

Tags: android

I have an application where you have to log in like an user with your password.

This application needs to be secure, so it needs to Log Out the user when he doesn´t tocuh the screen during a determinate period of time(let´s say, 5 minutes).

The problem is that, once the user is logged in, he can go through many activities, not only one, and I would like to know if there is a way in Android to know if the user can get Logged out after few minutes.

I was thinking about using the method onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev), but the problem is that, ¿do I have to use this method on every activities? ¿there is another easier way to manage it in Android?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing this on every `Activity`, you could create one `Activity` like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
```

and implement `onInterceptTouchEvent` in your `BaseActivity`.

Then from all other `Activities` you will have to extend the `BaseActivity`

**UPDATE:**
You will have to use `onTouch` if you want to listen for events in whole screen. This requires that in every xml file of your `Activity`, you will have to give an `id` for the root view of your xml (`Linearlayout`, `Relativelayout`, `Framelayout` or whatever). So in order to let your `BaseActivity` get inputs from other `Activities` you will have to pass your root view to it, like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        super.setRootView(findViewById(R.id.rootView));
    }
}

public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setRootView(View rootView){
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("BaseActivity", "onTouch!");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a possible solution to solve my problem! I am gonna try it, and to put "useful" on your comment if it was working! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok, I understood......But, now I have a problem. ¿How can I use the "onInterceptTouchEvent" method? I was checking, and it is a method from "ViewGroup"(so, it means, from LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc....But my BaseActivity doesn´t have any alyout!! How can I use it??? Anyone knows any tutorial???

Comment: I edited my answer mate and showed you an example to achieve what you want with onTouch.

Comment: Hello again mate!! I have a "little" problem, and it is that if I have views inside the "mainview" the BaseActivity don´t detect the TouchEvent. I mean, I have one RelativeLayout like the main one on one Activity, and then, on the middle, I have a button. When I press anywhere on the screen, everything works properly, but when I click on the Button, the BaseActivity "onTouch" method don´t detect the Activity, Any solutions please????? P.S: I am getting crazy with this problem........

Comment: that is probably because your onclicklistener takes focus from ontouchlistener. I recommend you add a new question to this!

Comment: Ok, I will ask about it to see if someone knows how can I fix that! Anyway, thanks a lot for all your help!!

Comment: Good luck mate, if I find something I will post it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** One way to achieve this would be to get current time (using `System.currentTimeMillis()`) as the user logs in to the application. Let's save this in a variable `t1`.

**2.** Start a service which will monitor/check/execute below things:

**2a.** whenever user touches any of your activities set the value of `t1` to current time.

**2b.** continuously get the current time (`t2`) and calculate the time-lapse between `t1` and `t2` (i.e. `t2 - t1`). If this time-lapse is equal to or greater than say 5 mins you can call the `logOut()` function.

Yes, you would have to inform the background service that user is present, from every activity. Although solution provided by **Carnal** would go a long way in reducing your effort to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! With both solutions, from Carnal and you, I think I can do it! Thanks a lot!!